Allowing httpd to view process state by pid of processes started by the same user
I am currently trying to allow a PHP application to manage background jobs - however this seems to be more difficult under selinux as it seems that the php process cannot access /proc/{pid} of other httpd processes.
Basically the objective is to determine two things:

is the process still running?
was the process launched by the correct (apache) user?

As a caveat, I am utterly clueless about SELinux, but my searches / man page reading didn't get me any further.
Any help would be much appreciated.

file_exists("/proc/$pid/status") - this fails with setenforce 1.
`"ps -o uname='' -p $pid" - also fails with setenforce 1
file_exists("/proc/$pid") itself, followed by checking the owner of the directory - the file_exists() portion works, but any checks on the directory fail
I've tried changing context on the /proc directory and grant httpd access wholesale, but apparently that is not possible.

Expectation would be a way to retrieve the two above mentioned data points via a php process:

process by pid is still running
process by pid is owned by a given owner


I don't have an answer to your question. However, when I see "allow a PHP application to manage background jobs" and "other httpd processes", I'm wondering if you are going down the best path to start with? Is there a reason that httpd would be used for background processes in the first place? Can you instead us PHP via cron or similar? You could create your own local PID equivalent to monitor when a process starts/stops then.

The /proc/{pid} directory gets the same SELinux context as the {pid} process.
So, you need to allow your PHP process to see that httpd_t directories exist, get their attributes (owner, group, permissions, ...) and to walk through such directories so the PHP process could read the /proc/{pid}/status file.
But you have to be aware of an issue (in terms of security): that the status file has the httpd_t SELinux type; so, if you allow the PHP process to open and read such files, you will also the PHP process to read many files under /proc/{pid}/ ! Luckily, many of them have rather protective DAC permissions.
To achieve your expectations, you need to compile a small piece of SELinux policy code.
You can choose to allow only what you need: allow the PHP process to getattr on httpd_t directories (it's enough to see the /proc/{pid} directory and to get it's owner).
Or you can choose to allow you PHP process to see ANY running process state using the kernel_search_proc() macro (on RedHat/CentOS/Fedora/Alma...)
